# How to know which device is connected in which /dev/ttyUSB port

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, tty, udev

I am using two Wavecom 16-port modems. When I attach the modems to my system, I am able to list of all the `/dev/ttyUSB` port names, but also I want to know, which modem is containing ports 0 to 16 and which one is containing ports 17 to 32?

The modems may be attached and removed many times in a single day, so I also want to keep logs when modems get disconnected and connected again.

Any idea how to do so using c/c++/php script/node.js ?

Comment: it is much easier to set up `udev` rules to assign persistent `tty` port names once and for all  instead of having to look them up every time

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can get this information from the `sys` filesystem. It is easy to check from the shell, and then do a program that does the same:

1. `cd /sys/devices`
2. Find the directory of the first of your ports: `find -name "ttyUSB0"`. It will probably  find them in something like `./pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.0/...`
3. The `pci*` part is the USB controller. The interesting bit is the `2-2.1` which is the USB device. In that directory there are a lot of files that identify your device:

   - `serial`: The serial number. Probably what you want.
   - `idVendor` and `idProduct`: The USB identifier of the device.

An easy alternatively to steps 1 and 2 is:

1. `cd /sys/class/tty/`
2. `readlink ttyUSBn` will give you the full path of the device directory.

As a footnote, note that some parts of the `sysfs` are considered API stable and some parts are not. For more information see the [official sysfs rules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/sysfs-rules.rst).

Comment: @Mayur- You're welcome! If you think this answers your question, please mark it as correct and closed.

Comment: Done that..!! Achieved my goal using udev library and your ans.. @_@