# STM UART over USB

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, uart

I have some device connected via USB to Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian installed.
I have protocol specification, it is simple serial protocol with hex commands and data.
However I have no idea, where to find drivers...
In `lsusb` I see:

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0483:5740 STMicroelectronics STM32F407
```

But [here](https://www.st.com) is nothing about UART<->USB drivers...

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -la /dev/ | grep ttyS` have no results also.

Comment: What about `ls -l /dev/ttyACM*` ?  Those are the nodes created for standard USB CDC ACM devices.

Comment: Yes, it is there, actually ) if you want, put it as answer, I will check it as right answer.

Comment: In my opinion this belongs to [SU](https://superuser.com). But even on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) there are literally dozens of duplicates like https://stackoverflow.com/q/13914226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `ls -l /dev/ttyACM*` ? Those are the nodes created for standard USB CDC ACM devices.